# PHP UPDATE IN CODEIGNETER 3

Tags: php

I want to change the database, but my coding deletes all its contents.
I use codeigneter 3

**my controller**:

```
public function update_() {

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
    $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
    $number = $this->input->post('number');
    $rekening = $this->input->post('rekening');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $data = array(
        'nama' => $nama,
        'alamat' => $alamat,
        'number' => $number,
        'rekening' => $rekening,
        'email' => $email,
    );
    $where  = array (
        'id' => $id
    );
    
    $this->Modellaptop->update_client($where, $data, 'tb_invoice ');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 
        '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Update success </div>'
    );
    redirect('Admin/invoice');
}
```

**my model**:

```
public function update_client($where,$data,$table)
{
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try like this

in controller

```
public function update_() {

$id = $this->input->post('id');
$nama = $this->input->post('nama');
$alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
$number = $this->input->post('number');
$rekening = $this->input->post('rekening');
$email = $this->input->post('email');

$data = [
    'nama' => $nama,
    'alamat' => $alamat,
    'number' => $number,
    'rekening' => $rekening,
    'email' => $email
];
$where  = array (
    'id' => $id
);

$this->Modellaptop->update_client($where, $data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 
    '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Update success </div>'
);
redirect('Admin/invoice');
```

}

in model

```
public function update_client($where,$data = [])
{
  $this->db->where($where);
  $this->db->update('tb_invoice(your table name)', $data);
  //dont forget to return
  return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```